# how to using a injected variable in compose preview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I have a fragment which has an injected variable timeZoneId, which now I have to pass to a composable.

```
@Inject
lateinit var timeZoneId: ZoneId
```

In Composable I have a preview, how can I add this to the preview as a parameter please.

```
@Composable
fun EditDepTime(
    timeZoneId: ZoneId,
    onCancelEditDepTime: () -> Unit
) {

}

@Preview
@Composable
fun EditDepartureTimePreview() {
    OhmeM3Theme() {
        EditDepartureTime(
            ZoneId, //Need to pass timezoneId here
            {}
        )
    }
}
```

What do I need to pass to get the preview to work please

Thanks
R

Comment: How could you possibly pass something to a preview that only exists at runtime? `timeZoneId` will be injected when your app is compiled and run. It's not available to use in a preview.

Comment: Hello @Tenfour thank you for responding, yes that is correct, so what needs to passed to the preview just to get it to work please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide some sample value to the preview because it doesn't have access to runtime values. Here you could put any ZoneId you like, for example:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun EditDepartureTimePreview() {
    OhmeM3Theme() {
        EditDepartureTime(
            ZoneId.systemDefault(),
            {}
        )
    }
}
```